# python - Django model query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've 2 models :

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255, primary_key = True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class B(models.Model):
    a_id = models.ForeignKey('A', related_name = 'pptls')
    some_unique_value = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
```

I want to get **destination** from `A` given the **some_unique_value** from `B`.

This is how I'm currently doing:-

```
a_id = B.objects.get(some_unique_value = "something").a_id
destination = A.objects.get(a_id = a_id).destination
```

Though, it fetches me the results, but I want to convert this into single line query, something like joins in SQL. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You use the double-underscore syntax to traverse relationships:

```
destination = A.objects.get(b__some_unique_value="something").destination
```

This is very well covered in [the documentation on making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

(Also, please don't name your ForeignKeys "_id": it doesn't represent an ID, it represents an actual object of the other class. Django automatically appends "_id" to the underlying database field anyway.)

Comment: Yaa, I'know that we shouldn't use `_id` in FK's, but alas my code has been built like that. I got to know it later. 
Thanks :)

Comment: what is `b` in `b__some_unique_value` ? is it the related_name ? which  in my case is `pptls`??

Comment: No, as mentioned in that documentation I linked to, it's the lower-case name of the related model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  how to Query Single element ? suppose to check if password to a username is correct in database userInfo?  SQL : SELECT password FROM userinfo WHERE password='mypassword'